# Expressing multiplication as percentage changes.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have seen many times that for example when we have a formula:
$$A=\frac{B\cdot C}{D}$$
where $A, B, C, D$ are some variables; we can express it in the following way as 'growth rates':$%\Delta%$
$$\frac{\Delta A}{A}=\frac{\Delta B}{B}+\frac{\Delta C}{C}-\frac{\Delta D}{D} $$
Why does it work this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can derive it by differentiation. Mutliply the original equation by $D$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
AD &=& BC \\
&& \\
AdD + DdA &=& CdB + BdC \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{differentiating using the product rule} \\
&& \\
\dfrac{dA}{A} &=& \dfrac{CdB + BdC - AdD}{AD} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{CdB + BdC}{BC} - \dfrac{dD}{D} \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{using $AD=BC$} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{dB}{B} + \dfrac{dC}{C} - \dfrac{dD}{D}.
\end{eqnarray*}